# I could not see my datepicker Android, phonegap

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

I have an app, which is delevoped on phonegap.

I used a slow date picker plugin, so I wanted to change it.

I search and find a usable one;

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/DatePicker

I followed steps.

But I do not see my date picker, only see an empty input element.

I created a package "com.phonegap.plugin" and put my "DatePickerPlugin.java" into this package.

I created "datePickerPlugin.js" and put it under assets/www file.

I included it to index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="datePickerPlugin.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="datePickerPlugin.js"></script>
```

I added a class="nativedatepicker" to my element

```
<input type="text" class="nativedatepicker" id="get_date" name="get_date" />
```

I put the code to script part of my index.html

```
$('.nativedatepicker').focus(function(event) {
    var currentField = $(this);
    var myNewDate = Date.parse(currentField.val()) || new Date();

    // Same handling for iPhone and Android
    window.plugins.datePicker.show({
        date : myNewDate,
        mode : 'date', // date or time or blank for both
        allowOldDates : true
    }, function(returnDate) {
        var newDate = new Date(returnDate);
        currentField.val(newDate.toString("dd/MMM/yyyy"));

        // This fixes the problem you mention at the bottom of this script with it not working a second/third time around, because it is in focus.
        currentField.blur();
    });
});

$('.nativetimepicker').focus(function(event) {
    var currentField = $(this);
    var time = currentField.val();
    var myNewTime = new Date();

    myNewTime.setHours(time.substr(0, 2));
    myNewTime.setMinutes(time.substr(3, 2));

    // Same handling for iPhone and Android
    plugins.datePicker.show({
        date : myNewTime,
        mode : 'time', // date or time or blank for both
        allowOldDates : true
    }, function(returnDate) {
      // returnDate is generated by .toLocaleString() in Java so it will be relative to the current time zone
        var newDate = new Date(returnDate);
        currentField.val(newDate.toString("HH:mm"));

        currentField.blur();
    });
});
```

Finally, I put the plugin to my plugins.xml

```
<plugin name="DatePickerPlugin" value="com.phonegap.plugin.DatePickerPlugin"/>
```

Where is my error?

I use cordova-1.9.0 and Android 2.2. Also  I have included my Cordova library file.

I nearly looked all questions about this error in stackoverflow, I did not find any efficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

U can try this to get Date.

```
function  ShowDatePicker(){

                        var currentField = $('#nativedate');
                        var myNewDate = Date.parse(currentField.val()) || new Date();

                        // Same handling for iPhone and Android
                        window.plugins.datePicker.show({
                            date : myNewDate,
                            mode : 'date', // date or time or blank for both
                            allowOldDates : true
                        }, function(returnDate) {
                            var newDate = new Date(returnDate);

                            var curr_date = newDate.getDate();
                            var curr_month = newDate.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
                            var curr_year = newDate.getFullYear();
                            if(curr_month < '10' || curr_month < 10 )
                                {
                                curr_month ='0'+curr_month.toString(); 
                                }

                            currentField.val(curr_date + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_year);

                            // This fixes the problem you mention at the bottom of this script with it not working a second/third time around, because it is in focus.
                            currentField.blur();
                        });
                    }
```

Change

```
<input type="text" class="nativedatepicker" id="get_date" name="get_date" />
```

to

```
<input type="text"  id="nativedate" onclick="ShowDatePicker();" name="get_date" />
```